# JSF/ Javascript error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have developed a JSF 2.0 application in Netbeans IDE which is working correctly in my browser but when I deployed it on client side , it is giving me error: PRIMEFACES IS UNDEFINED

Does anyone have idea about the error? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you added primefaces.jar in your lib folder inside web-inf?

Comment: yes. PrimeFaces 3.4.jar is added in libraries folder

Comment: How to solve this error?

Comment: "deployed it on client side" sounds very strange. You normally deploy it to a server and have the client access it via an URL. Or did you mean the application's customer when you said "client side"? In web development world, the "client side" represents the enduser who's using your web application via a webbrowser. In any case, please check the browser's HTTP traffic monitor and JS console once again if any HTTP traffic went as expected and if there aren't more JS errors preceding the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt have a head tag you will get that error. 
You need to add the PrimeFaces namespace at the head tag.

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Your xhtml page should like this-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

    <h:head>  

    </h:head>  

    <h:body>  

        <p:spinner />  

    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Please have a look at [PrimeFAQ #2](http://primefaces.org/faq.html) and [PrimeStartGuide](http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html).

Comment: @yup..I dont understand that application is working correctly in my browser but not in client's browser. I have added head tag and namespace as well

Comment: can you please check client's browser with your browser version?

Comment: OP explicitly stated *"which is working correctly in my browser"*. This is impossible if the `<h:head>` was indeed absent. Also the absence of PrimeFaces namespace would impossibly have caused this error, because the PrimeFaces components requiring this JS wouldn't be rendered at all. So, the OP definitely has the `<h:head>` already set and the namespace already declared. Therefore, your answer is completely useless.

Comment: @BalusC - I didn't face this issue till now. I have made this referance as the primefaces website faq#2 stated. Thank you.

Comment: What part exactly of *"which is working correctly in my browser"* in the question didn't you understand? That would have been impossible if `<h:head>` is absent, right?

Comment: ok, is it possible for this error if the user have not added `primefaces.jar` in `glassfish/lib` directory?

Comment: No, then the PrimeFaces components requiring `primefaces.js` code would in first place not have generated their HTML output at all and therefore impossibly have caused specifically the JS error "PrimeFaces is undefined".